# Django - initial load/seed of model attributes from a CSV?

Tags: python, django

I have a CSV with ~500 columns that represent data I need to use in my Django app in a single model.

I don't want to manually go through and declare 500 attributes in my `models.py` file for this new model.

Is there some way to bootstrap this or make it easier?

Comment: A table with 500 columns seems a little excessive, how is the type of each column determined and are there columns containing duplicate values?

Comment: Agree it sounds excessive but it's all relevant data. Maybe I could trim it down a good amount but even if I'm left with 150 that's still a ton to do by hand.

In an ideal world, some function would read the values from each column and determine what the appropriate type is based on the values. I'm sure there are duplicate values between the rows but each column is unique.